Qdrant takes 25 second to retrieve 1000 single products
We have a single-product API that is causing us problems when called in large numbers (not even very large; 1000 requests take 25 seconds to finish).
What Are We Using
So, we are using Qdrant for our product database because of the semantic vector search capabilities. But also, we want to use it for the single-product API, which does nothing other than taking the ID and giving back the payload. When called with a single ID, it takes 70-90 ms to finish. But calling 1000 concurrent requests causes it to slow and return responses to all of them in 25-30 seconds. And while these 1000 requests are being processed, if we call it with one single ID, this time it takes 2500 ms (from 70-90 went to 2500 ms).
The API
This is the single product api:
def retrieve(self, request, pk):
        search_lang = request.query_params.get("language", "tr")
        country = request.query_params.get("country", "tr")
        payload = search.get_single_product(search_lang=search_lang, point_id=int(pk))
        payload["extra"] = functions.generate_extra_fields(
            product_id=payload["id"],
            total_rating_count=payload["stats"]["total_rating_count"],
            lang=search_lang,
            country=country,
        )
        return Response(
            {"data": payload},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        ) 

The search function
And this is the get_single_product function:

def get_single_product(search_lang: str, point_id: int):
    """
    Retrieves a single product based on the provided language and product ID.

    Parameters:
        search_lang (str): The language code for the product.
        point_id (int): The ID of the product to retrieve.

    Returns:
        dict: A dictionary containing the details of the retrieved product.

    Note:
        - This function retrieves the language code from the environment variable LANGUAGE_KEY_MAP.
        - It uses the Qdrant client to retrieve the product from the appropriate language collection.
        - If the provided search language is not supported, it returns an empty dictionary.
    """
    lang = int(LANGUAGE_KEY_MAP.get(search_lang))
    qd_client = qdrant_client()
    if not lang:
        return 0
    search_results = qd_client.retrieve(
        collection_name=f"lang{lang}_products",
        ids=[point_id],
    )
    qd_client.close()
    payloads = []
    for search_result in search_results:
        payloads.append(search_result.payload)
    return payloads[0] if len(payloads) > 0 else []

How I tested with 1000 requests:
For testing, I first need to have the ids of 1000 products. Our main relational DB is pg, so I first retrieve the ids, then create async requests; as below:
test.py:
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from utils.functions import pg_connect
import time

pg_start = time.time()
pg_connection, pg_cursor = pg_connect()
query = "SELECT id from public.products limit 1000;"
# Execute the query
pg_cursor.execute(query)

# Fetch IDs
ids = [row[0] for row in pg_cursor.fetchall()]
pg_connection.close()
pg_cursor.close()

print(f"it took {time.time() - pg_start} seconds to get ids from pg.\n")


async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def fetch_all(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        task_start = time.time()
        tasks = [fetch(session, url) for url in urls]
        print(f"tasks created at {time.time() -task_start} seconds. \n")
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def main(ids):
    base_url = "https://api2.markabu.com/v1/product/"
    url_start = time.time()
    urls = [f"{base_url}{id}/" for id in ids]
    print(f"urls created in {time.time() - url_start} seconds.\n")
    request_start = time.time()
    responses = await fetch_all(urls)
    print(f"responses came in {time.time() - request_start} seconds.\n")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main(ids))

The results
I ran the code a few times, the results are within 5% of each other, one example:
it took 0.00798797607421875 seconds to get ids from pg.

urls created in 0.00010538101196289062 seconds.

tasks created at 0.00011730194091796875 seconds. 

responses came in 26.443119525909424 seconds.

What is the problem?
So, there are different areas which may cause the problem. Before blaming Qdrant or my own data structure, I thought about web server issues which may have problems distributing a large (fairly large) number of requests. That is why I created a simple API that just returns a simple message. Then called it even more than 100,000 times, and for almost 130,000 calls, it took only 8-9 seconds.
So, the problem is not with the web server, nor the Django backend.
What about data structure?
One other thing to consider is that our products have 30 columns (sorry for using 'column' to refer to JSON structured data in Qdrant, but you know what I mean), some of which are fairly large JSON fields (such as variants, which for some products may be a list of 10-20 variants, each containing data about different variants of the product).
Can Qdrant actually handle large amounts of concurrent query requests?
Another possibility to consider is Qdrant's limitations. I could not find any note about concurrent requests in Qdrant. Or, perhaps the problem lies in how I handle the qdrant_client. I open the client using a simple function called in the get_single_product function above:
qdrant_client = QdrantClient(
            host=kwargs.get("host"),
            port=kwargs.get("port"),
            timeout=kwargs.get("timeout"),
        )
        return qdrant_client 

And after using it to get the product, I close the connection (refer to get_single_product function above).
UPDATE
Details about Qdrant setup
I am hosting Qdrant on a docker container on my server, with 30 cores of CPU and 50 GBs of RAM. This is the docker-compose for the container:
 qdrant:
    image: qdrant/qdrant:v1.8.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6333:6333"
      - "6334:6334"
    volumes:
      - qdrant_data:/qdrant/storage

Also my qdrant collections are created in this manner:
client.recreate_collection(
        collection_name=collection_name,
        vectors_config=models.VectorParams(
            size=encoder.get_sentence_embedding_dimension(),
            distance=models.Distance.DOT,
        ),
    )

Which I do not think is relevant to the problem, but included here if needed. If any more details on the structure of the project is needed, please ask.

Could you please share some details on where your Qdrant server is hosted? What does the cluster setup look like?

Sure, I am updating the qeustion right now.

I guess you are using gRPC. You can try using rest api or provide details about how you established your grpc connection.

You should use payload indexing, this will reduce the search time significantly though will eat up some RAM but its worth it.
PUT /collections/{collection_name}/index
{
    "field_name": "language",
    "field_schema": "keyword"  
}

If it is already indexed, then you may try batch search feature of qdrant DB.

I am not searching for enything, but simply retrieving single points using their ids. I do not understand how indexing the payload should help here?
